# How can I execute AppleScript from Textedit?

Tags: macos, applescript, textedit

I have the following AppleScript code in a Textedit file:

```
set the clipboard to (do shell script "date +%d/%m/%y")
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke tab using command down
    keystroke "v" using command down
end tell
```

How can I execute this code?

Comment: I've edited the question some more to also make sure the title matches the content.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is is you're trying to do? Are you really just trying to insert the date in your TextEdit document at the cursor?

Answer (score 4):

You can't execute AppleScript directly from TextEdit. Apple provides an AppleScript editor though in `/Applications/Utilities/Script\ Editor.app` which makes it easy to create and run AppleScript code.

Just navigate to `/Applications/Utilities` in Finder, run `Script Editor` and copy/paste your code into it.

Answer (score 2):

If this is something you find yourself needing to do fairly often (and, for some reason, don't wish to have to use *Script Editor*), then one way to do this is to create a systemwide **Service** (or **Quick Action**) in *`Automator`*:

[image: Run As AppleScript Service]

It will be set to receive **`text in any application`** and ensure that the **`Output replaces selected text`**.

Once saved, you can select the text in *`TextEdit`* (or, indeed, any application), and have it execute the AppleScript in situ, returning the result, which will appear below the selection.

**AppleScript code:**

```
on run {{input}}
    local input

    try
        return {input, run script input}
    on error E
        return {input, E}
    end try
end run
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to make an edit in order to retract my up-vote. The reason I did this is because while your answer works in some cases, it also fails in some cases. I can cause the Automator service hang with simple basic AppleScript code. Therefore, this is not a viable answer.

Comment: @user3439894 Can you be more specific?

Comment: Take the code in the OP as an example. As is, run by your Service it fails as TextEdit would not have focus when System Events runs the keystrokes. Add a `tell application "TextEdit" to activate` after the `set the clipboard ...` and the Automator service just keeps running in the menu bar and never gets above 0% complete.  Even just selecting `tell application "TextEdit" to activate` by itself hangs the Automator service.